Puzzlement on PEBs reservation in Linux UBIFS
I am working on an embedded Linux system (kernel-5.10.24), and the system is using 128MB NAND FLASH as storage.
I enabled the MTD and UBIFS in the kernel, and divided the NAND FLASH into 3 MTD devices, MTD1 is for rootfs with 60MB, MTD2 is for userdata with 60MB.
When I boot the system up, I found there were 2 UBI devices (UBI0 and UBI1), and found following kernel log about PEB reservation.
ubi0 warning: 0x803ce56c: cannot reserve enough PEBs for bad PEB handling, reserved 10, need 20
......
ubi0: good PEBs: 480, bad PEBs: 0, corrupted PEBs: 0

......
......
ubi1 warning: 0x803ce56c: cannot reserve enough PEBs for bad PEB handling, reserved 10, need 20
......
ubi1: good PEBs: 480, bad PEBs: 0, corrupted PEBs: 0

I got confused on the warning message, so I added more logs to kernel, and got.
[    1.891124] ubi0: attaching mtd1
[    1.891140] get_bad_peb_limit: max_beb_per1024: 20, limit: 20, device_size: 134217728, dev_pebs: 1024
....
[    2.013425] ubi1: attaching mtd2
[    2.013440] get_bad_peb_limit: max_beb_per1024: 20, limit: 20, device_size: 134217728, dev_pebs: 1024

Now I got even more confused:

Why kernel says the device_size is 128MB, not 60MB? I think kernel work on the MTD device, which is 60MB not the whole NAND FLASH.
Is the wear leveling of this settings (10 PEBs are actually reserved for each MTD, and 20 PEBs in total) impacted?
Can UBI do wear leveling across MTD devices? I am not sure about it.
How can fix above warning messages?

